# g++: -Werror=format suppressed automatically in files included from /usr/include yocto SDK folder

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, g++, yocto

I am trying to add a safe string formatting method similar to sprintf using variadic macro and deliver it as a system header and a shared object in a Yocto based SDK. Based on the location of the header file, two different behavior is observed during compilation.

MyMacro.hpp

```
#ifndef MYMACRO_HPP
#define MYMACRO_HPP

extern std::string stringFormat( const char* fmt, ... ) __attribute__ ((format(printf, 1, 2)));

#define FORMAT_STRING( fmt, ...) stringFormat( fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__ )

#endif //MYMACRO_HPP
```

MyMacro.cpp

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdarg>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::string stringFormat( const char* fmt, ... )
{
    va_list args1;
    va_start( args1, fmt );
    va_list args2;
    va_copy( args2, args1 );
    std::vector<char> buf( 1 + std::vsnprintf( nullptr, 0, fmt, args1 ) );
    va_end( args1 );
    std::vsnprintf( buf.data( ), buf.size( ), fmt, args2 );
    va_end( args2 );

    return std::string( buf.data( ), buf.data( ) + buf.size( ) );
}
```

libMyMacro.so is generated using the following command:

```
g++ -Wall -std=gnu++0x -shared -fPIC -o libMyMacro.so MyMacro.cpp
```

Usage:
main.cpp

```
#include <cstdarg>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

#include "mytest/MyMacro.hpp"

int main()
{
    std::string myString = FORMAT_STRING( "%s %s", "test" );
    std::printf( "%s", myString.c_str( ) );
}
```

When compiling main.cpp by placing MyMacro.hpp under /usr/mytest/ reports the following error as expected:

```
sh-4.3$ g++ -Wall -Werror -std=gnu++0x -I /usr/ -L /usr/lib/ -lMyMacro main.cpp 
In file included from main.cpp:5:0:
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
/usr/mytest/MyMacro.hpp:6:67: error: format '%s' expects a matching 'char*' argument [-Werror=format=]
 #define FORMAT_STRING( fmt, ...) stringFormat( fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__ )
                                                                   ^
main.cpp:9:28: note: in expansion of macro 'FORMAT_STRING'
     std::string myString = FORMAT_STRING( "%s %s", "test" );
                            ^
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Now if MyMacro.hpp is placed under /usr/include/mytest/ folder, g++ reports no error on compiling using the following command:

```
g++ -Wall -Werror -std=gnu++0x -I /usr/include/ -L /usr/lib/ -lMyMacro main.cpp
```

Why is there a difference in the compilation output based on the location of the header file?

### Update:

GCC is configured with /usr/include and /usr/local/include as default system header path in this SDK.

To report error from system headers, use -Wsystem-headers option though this activates warnings and errors in all included system header files:

```
g++ -Wall -Werror -Wsystem-headers -std=gnu++0x -I /usr/include/ -L /usr/lib/ -lMyMacro main.cpp
```

Comment: g++ won't find files under `/usr/include/mytest/` folder with these flags. Please use `g++ -H` to see what files really get included.

Comment: g++ does find the header file - `g++ -H` indicates the following file: `/usr/include/mytest/MyMacro.hpp`

Comment: sorry my bad, didn't see you `#include "mytest/MyMacro.hpp"`.

Comment: The is related to [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-Headers.html) and [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2000-05/msg01044.html) - gcc disables warnings in system headers by default. May be there exists a way to enable warning in system headers selectively?

Comment: Yes, since the macro is defined in a system header, its expansion is immune to certain warnings. The [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-Headers.html) says the list of these warning is determined ad-hoc, and `-Wformat` is apparently included in the list. I believe this is a bug. There is no reason to suppress this warning.